# Configuring SQL server 2005 enterprise edition

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

What are the basic settings required for running SQL server 2005 enterprise edition in a local computer. When i take program from start menu it shows only sql server configuration manager, surface area manager, error reporting and a command prompt. There is no SQL server launching shortcut. How i get it?

Answer (score 1):

you need sql server management Studio
http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en